# Can't parse tcpdump output correctly

Tags: parsing, stdout, stderr, tcpdump

I'm trying to run this command: `sudo tcpdump "ether proto 0x888e and ether host <BSSID>" -I -w -U -vvv -I <INTERFACENAME> -w ~/Desktop/handshake.cap` which works perfectly in terms of its function, however, when I run the command, I get the following output:

```
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 262144 bytes
Got 0
```

Where `Got 0` counts the number of packets captured. Furthermore when stopping the command, I get the following:

```
tcpdump: listening on en0, link-type IEEE802_11_RADIO (802.11 plus radiotap header), capture size 262144 bytes
^C0 packets captured
3526 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

I'm trying to integrate this command into a script and would simply like  everything but `Got 0` to be omitted from the output.

I have experienced this sort of problem before but have simply used `2> /dev/null` to get rid of the output I don't want. However, it seems that `Got 0` is included in this blocked output and as a result, I get no output at all. Similarly, `&>/dev/null` removes all output as well. I have also tried piping it to `sed -n '1!p'` to ignore the first line but this has no effect and would not be preferable because in theory it would not remove `0 packets captured
3526 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel`

Is anyone aware of how to resolve this issue?

Thank you in advance for any help,

Kind regards, Rocco

P.S. I am running macOS